# Create custom date format using DateTimeFormatterBuilder and ignore raw text between Chrono Fields

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I try to create a robust solution to support different date formats using DateTimeFormatterBuilder.

I want to be able to parse almost any date string the user is providing by only knowing the order of the day/month/year/hours/minutes/seconds.

I thought of two solutions:

1. using regex to replace all the known delimiters by a specific delimiter (for example "?") and using a DateTimeFormatterBuilder to create a custom date format.
2. basically the same thing, but instead I will provide a list of "known" delimiters and will append them as optional to theDateTimeFormatterBuilder

**Note**: one of the problems we are having is inconsistent spaces between the date time ingredients (example: dd_MM YYYY or dd_____MM__YYYY)

**Note 2**: performance is crucial

**My question:** is there any way to avoid all of this and use some builtin method to ignore the text between the year,month,day,.. etc (something like optional)

Solution 1 (for simplicity assume the order is day-month-year):

```
private static final String[] DELIMITER= {"?"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    appendDelims(builder);
    builder.appendValueReduced(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR,1,2,1);
    appendDelims(builder);
    builder.appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 4, LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0));
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = builder.toFormatter();
    System.out.println("dt = " + LocalDate.parse("23     2,,,,05".replaceAll("\\s+|-+|,+","?"),dateTimeFormatter));
    System.out.println("dt2 = " + LocalDate.parse("09-----2      2015".replaceAll("\\s+|-+|,+","?"), dateTimeFormatter));
}

private static void appendDelims(DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtb) {
    for(String d : DELIMITER) {
        dtb.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(d));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
dt = 2005-02-23
dt2 = 2015-02-09
```

Solution 2:

```
private static final String[] DELIMITER= {"?","-"," ","  "};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    appendDelims(builder);
    builder.appendValueReduced(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR,1,2,1);
    appendDelims(builder);
    builder.appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 4, LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0));
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = builder.toFormatter();
    System.out.println("dt = " + LocalDate.parse("23?2 05",dateTimeFormatter));
    System.out.println("dt2 = " + LocalDate.parse("9?2-2015", dateTimeFormatter));
}

private static void appendDelims(DateTimeFormatterBuilder dtb) {
    for(String d : DELIMITER) {
        dtb.appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(d));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
dt = 2005-02-23
dt2 = 2015-02-09
```

Comment: For the spaces you can remove all the spaces using replace method and then implement your logic.

Comment: If you are serious about performance (like if parsing a million date strings with a minimal wait), you may want to see if writing your own parser from the ground up can outperform `DateTimeFormatter`. It would be the first time I had heard about this being important enough to do that, though.

Comment: performance is important, but I am looking for some-thing simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no reasonable way to avoid either your solution 1 or your solution 2. The only mechanisms available in `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to ignore different delimiters are those to make parts of the format optional:

1. `appendOptional` that you are already using
2. `optionalStart` and `optionalEnd`
3. square brackets `[` and `]` in the format pattern.

Of course there are other possibilities, like writing your own parser from the ground up, but none that I would really recommend over what you are already doing.

In your solution 1, since you are replacing the delimiters, I believe you don’t need the calls to `appendDelims`. The following formatter works for me for your two example date strings:

```
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                .appendPattern("?M?")
                .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 4, LocalDate.EPOCH)
                .toFormatter();
```

PS Don’t use `appendValueReduced` for month, it’s just confusing. Use a single pattern letter `M` to match month number in either 1 or 2 digits, e.g., `8`, `08` or `11`.